# Set-AuthenticodeSignature returns access to the path is denied error

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have a simple powershell script that I use to send me an email when there is an issue on a server.  Scripts are restricted from running on that server unless they're signed.  So, I created a self signed certificate, moved it to the trusted root folder, and when I run `Get-ChildItem` on it I see the thumbprint returned, and the properties look correct to me (though I admit I don't know much about certificates).  The last step is to sign the script, which I'm attempting to do with:

```
$cert=(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -CodeSigningCert)[0]
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath "C:\Scripts\ServiceFailureAlert.PS1" $cert
```

But I'm getting Access to the path is denied.
I'm sure that its something super simple, but I'm banging my head against the wall at this point.  The script is something that I created.  Its not read only, the directory isn't read only, all users have full rights, I'm an admin on the server, I'm running powershell as an admin.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) to me are a bit strange... Both parameters `-FilePath` AND `-Certificate` are positional parameters on position `1`. Perhaps if you use them both Named? `Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath "C:\Scripts\ServiceFailureAlert.PS1" -Certificate $cert`

Comment: I tried with -Certificate and without and still getting the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The action was being blocked by an application on the server that I didn't have visibility to.  I spoke with the server team, got rights added, and re-ran the command without issue.  Everything works now.  Thanks for the look/response Theo, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue and under the Security event log I found the following:

```
Audit Failure:

Cryptographic Operation:
Operation:  Open Key.
Return Code:    0x80090016
```

The problem for me was that the user which was signing the scripts was a different user than the one I had used to import the certificates, and didn't have access to the private keys. To fix, I did the following:

1. Manage Certificates for Local Computer
2. Locate the Authenticode Certificate with the private key
3. Right click > All tasks > Manage private keys...
4. Granted the user Full Control over the private keys

After this I was able to use `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` under my desired user credential with no issues